# TeXstudio continuously attempts to compile dummy files and crashes

Tags: texstudio

I keep getting error messages like this on TeXstudio:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "ka4772".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "la4772".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "ma4772".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "na4772".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "oa4772".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "pa4772".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "qa4772".tex

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "ka4772".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "la4772".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -halt-on-error  "ma4772".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

It seems like it is trying to compile a bunch of non-existent files. Is there some setting I need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like active preview mode.

Apparently, you have used the preview mode on a bunch of code. It can be switched on by selecting a bit of code and press `Alt+P`. If you are editing this bit, TexStudio will continuously try to compile it. So do a right-click in the area where you are editing and click on `Clear Inline Preview`.

Answer (score -5):

Short answer: I don't use TeXstudio to avoid that kind of stuff

Long answer: I'm both on MacOS and on Linux and use LaTEX profusely. I found that I can drive my editing process with `latexmk` (provided in MacTEX and the Ubuntu .deb packages by default) on both systems:

1. editor: I'm using emacs25 on both, same customisation (i.e. same `$HOME/.emacs.d` infrastructure) What 'extras' on emacs? `yasnippets` are a life saver, spellchecking with `flyspell` driving `aspell`
2. PDF viewer: It has to support `synctex`. On MacOS I'm using `Skim.app` and on Linux a small Python script extending `evince` (a basic version is a DuckDuckGo away ;-) )

And that should be it. You need to customise `$HOME/.latexmkrc` to your editor and viewer, but that should be it. It is a no-nonsense setup that avoids producing extra processes, files, etc.