# My TeXstudio Console shows that pdflatex.exe is starting weird processes

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

It seems to be starting processes on random generated files like `"bcJEyK".tex`.
As far as I can tell, these files don't even exist on my system.

On the screenshot below you can see my TeXstudio settings. I worked with all these settings for about one week and never had anything like that appear in the console. Then somehow, without changing any settings, these console outputs started appearing.
They appear very randomly every few minutes or so. Sometimes just one or two lines appear, and sometimes five at almost the same second.

My Console output is german, here is the translation:

Prozess gestartet == **Process started**

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n) == **Process finished with Error(s)**

```
Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "bcJEyK".tex

Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ZFSpkU".tex

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "mOKvrF".tex

Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "VEvEYR".tex

Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "bANUcz".tex

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

[image]

Comment: Uh, I had that too, and I think the issue popped out also here. IIRC it was resolved in some update. Which version of TeXStudio do you have?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474290/82917

Comment: @campa I got version TeXstudio 3.1.1
Thanks for providing the link. I can confirm that by marking some source code and pressing `ALT+P` a message like shown in original post will appear in console, and it will also exit with an error.
However, I am pretty sure that I have have used ALT+P anywhere because it highlights the code purple, and I would have noticed that.
Anyway, I went through all of my .tex files, marked all code with `CTRL+A` and rightclicked on that to select "Clear Inline Preview", but sadly it didn't help.
Is there maybe a way to just disable all automatic compiling?

Comment: That looks like you are asking for synchronous processing (type a bit, get it processed/displayed). Presumably the system creates random-named files to do the processing, and they are often wrong (started an environment, haven't closed it yet).

Comment: @vonbrand yes, probably! But I don't want any synchronous processing. Any idea how I can disable that?