# Why does TeX studio run pdflatex in the background?

Tags: texstudio

TeX Studio seems to sometimes run pdflatex in the background even when I don't ask it to compile. The Messages pane shows something like this:

```
Process started: sh -c "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape -output-directory=build "cIbKph".tex"

Process started: sh -c "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape -output-directory=build "HyLUSQ".tex"

Process started: sh -c "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape -output-directory=build "Hynxwj".tex"

Process exited normally

Process exited normally

Process exited normally
```

Why does TeX Studio do this and is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but IIRC that is when a preview option is active. Never used it, but e.g. when the mouse pointer runs over an equation, the equation result is displayed on screen.

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474290/82917