pdflatex automatically running a non-existing .tex file
When I compile my .tex document in Texstudio using pdflatex, after the process exit normally after processing the desired .tex file, sometimes it randomly start a process on a non-existing .tex file.
The following is a screenprint of my message box. I don't have a .text file named mOxGAb.tex. So why pdflatex runs it and says process exited with errors.


welcome! something in code you've not shown or in configuration settings you've not shown causes your editor to initiate compilation of that file. does that string of characters appear in anywhere in any file in your working directory? and please paste errors etc. as text. images can't be accessed by screenreaders, can't be indexed and can't be searched.

Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474290/110998, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71356087/7032505 . Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474301/110998 answer your question?
